# Assigning operators into an R variable

Tags: r, function, operators

I am trying to create a function where users can select the operator they want to use, which result in a different output. But I can't seem to get it to work. I know that we can't assign operators into an R object and then use it as an operator based on the R object name. Is there a way I could do this? Or perhaps a better way to write the function?

```
test <- function(items, operator = "+"){
bank_alpha <- matrix(ncol=6)
colnames(bank_alpha) <- colnames(bank_alpha, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Q")
colnames(bank_alpha)[6] <- "A"
alphabet <- LETTERS[seq(1:26)]

 for (i in 1:items) {
  item <- c(alphabet[i], alphabet[i operator 1], alphabet[i operator  2], alphabet[i operator  3], alphabet[i operator  4], alphabet[i operator 5])
  bank_alpha <- rbind(bank_alpha, item)
  bank_alpha <- na.omit(bank_alpha)
}
return(bank_alpha)
}

  test(items=4, operator = "-")
```

Comment: You want to use the "operator" argument as a function inside `test`? I.e. `operator = "+"; match.fun(operator)(1, 3)`? There are plenty examples of higher level R functions that accept functions as inputs (e.g. `Reduce`, `lapply`, `outer` etc)

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out do.call, which takes the name of a function as an argument. With

```
operator <- "+"
do.call(operator, list(2,3)
```

you will get `5` as the result.

In your example:

```
test <- function(items, operator = "+"){
  bank_alpha <- matrix(ncol=6)
  colnames(bank_alpha) <- colnames(bank_alpha, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Q")
  colnames(bank_alpha)[6] <- "A"
  alphabet <- LETTERS[seq(1:26)]

  for (i in 1:items) {
    item <- c(alphabet[i], alphabet[do.call(operator, list(i,1))], alphabet[do.call(operator, list(i,2))], alphabet[do.call(operator, list(i,3))], alphabet[do.call(operator, list(i,4))], alphabet[do.call(operator, list(i,5))])
    bank_alpha <- rbind(bank_alpha, item)
    bank_alpha <- na.omit(bank_alpha)
  }
  return(bank_alpha)
}

test(items=4, operator = "*")
```

Beware, "-" doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed.  You are right regarding the "-". Thank you!

Comment: If it solved your question, don't hesitate to accept it as answer :)

Comment: Note there will be a large number of function lookups if you use "do.call" like this, which will lead to a large performance overhead. I would recommend passing a function to "test" instead, possibly using the infix notation (see answer below) if that seems to lead to more readable code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `get()` functionally to dynamically call the operator functions, e.g.:

```
> get('+')(5, 2)
[1] 7
```

The `get()` function takes a string as input and returns a reference to the function corresponding to that string, if it exists.

Usually operators are called with one function argument on the left and one on the right (e.g. `5 + 2`).

The `+` operator function itself however just takes two arguments as input:

```
> args('+')
function (e1, e2) 
NULL
```

This is why we can call it as we did above.

Comment: This is very handy to know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own operators in R using the `%` sign, which would allow you to use the infix notation in your code. See a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179457) for more details.

```
test <- function(items, `%op%` = `+`){
    bank_alpha <- matrix(ncol=6)
    colnames(bank_alpha) <- colnames(bank_alpha, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Q")
    colnames(bank_alpha)[6] <- "A"
    alphabet <- LETTERS[seq(1:26)]

    for (i in 1:items) {
       item <- c(alphabet[i], alphabet[i %op% 1], alphabet[i %op% 2], alphabet[i %op% 3], alphabet[i %op% 4], alphabet[i %op% 5])
       bank_alpha <- rbind(bank_alpha, item)
       bank_alpha <- na.omit(bank_alpha)
    }
    return(bank_alpha)
}

test(items=4, `%op%` = `*`)
```

Comment: I always wanted to create a function that uses the %function%. Now I can. This is a great example. Thank you so much!