# Can I use a relation or a condition as a variable in a function?

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, relation

For example let's be a vector `ttt <- c(1,5,7,2,6)` and suppose that we want a vector with `ttt`'s elements bigger than 2. Then we have to write `ttt[ttt>2]`.

Can we have a function `TF_sequense(,)`, witch does this thing by writing `TF_sequense(ttt,>2)`?

I tried `do.call()` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316116/assigning-operators-into-an-r-variable) question, but I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
 TF_sequence <- function(vec, expr) {
               obj1 <- deparse(substitute(vec))
               eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s[%s%s]", obj1, obj1, expr)))
  }

 TF_sequence(ttt, ">2")
```