# Are binary operators / infix functions in R generic? And how to make use of?

Tags: r, generic-programming, infix-operator

From http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html or [R: What are operators like %in% called and how can I learn about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179457/r-what-are-operators-like-in-called-and-how-can-i-learn-about-them) I learned that it is possible to write own "binary operators" or "infix functioncs" using the `%`-sign.
One example would be

```
'%+%' <- function(a, b) a*b
x <- 2
y <- 3
x %+% y # gives 6
```

But is it possible to use them in a generic way if they are from a pre-defined class (so that in some cases I don't have to use the `%`-sign)? For exampple `x + y` shall give `6` if they are from the class `prod`.

Comment: This is how `ggplot2` works - `ggplot(data,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()` uses an overridden `+` method.

Comment: The quick answer is "yes". When you search on `?Ops` you should see the option of looking at 2 help pages that confirm this for either S3 or S4 styles of function definition.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: use `'+.<class name>' <- function()`.

### Examples

```
'+.product' <- function(a, b) a * b
'+.expo' <- function(a, b) a ^ b

m <- 2; class(m) <- "product"
n <- 3; class(n) <- "product"

r <- 2; class(r) <- "expo"
s <- 3; class(s) <- "expo"

m + n # gives 6
r + s # gives 8
```

### safety notes

The new defined functions will be called if at least one of the arguments is from the corresponding class `m + 4` gives you `2 * 4 = 8` and not `2 + 4 = 6`. If the classes don't match, you will get an error message (like for `r + m`). So all in all, be sure that you want to establish a new function behind such basic functions like `+`.

Comment: I think it would be fairly unwise to use "prod`' as a class name because it is also an R function name. You might also consider including references to appropriate help pages to improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you @42- for the hints. I changed it to `product`. If I find useful help pages, I will include them.