# Define new operator for tilde / formula

Tags: r, operators

I'm trying to code a new operator, a double tilde `~~`, to denote a different kind of formula to be passed onto another function (e.g., mirroring the functionality of `~~` in the `lavaan` package [lavaan syntax](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html)).

The issue is `y ~~ x` returns `y ~ ~x`, where the second `~` is returned with the predictors.

I am at a total loss here. It seems `~` is a primitive function `.Primitive("~")` with no methods, unlike, say, `+`. So existing tutorials for S3 methods are useless.

Is this a dead end and am I doing something really  against the programming language? Or is there an easy solution I am missing?

Comment: The same reason you cannot use `-` in variable names (`my-var`) is the reason you cannot use `~`. But you can use `´%~%´` for example: `´%~%´` `<- function (e1, e2) {e1*e2}` and use `3 %~% 4`
`

Comment: Rather than trying to fight with the parser, you are probably better off taking the formula as a string and parsing the syntax, as `lavaan` does with `lavParseModelString`.

Comment: @Drey sounds like the best option, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, if you accept the comment, I can make an answer out of it:

`~` is an operator in **R** like `+`,`-`, `/`,`*`. Although it is possible to use many kinds of characters for your variables using ticks `xxx`  and qoute "xxx" you also need to access them with ticks (see `?Reserved`). (I'm gonna use quotes instead of ticks here, but consider using ticks for a more accepted style guide.)

R is a functional programming language and therefore you can access every single language statement as a function, e.g. `a + b` is the same as `"+"(a, b)`. When you write `a + b` it is just syntactic sugar - language-wise it is translated into a primitive function call with two arguments.

To complicate things, there is an order of evaluation. So if you write `a~~b` it gets translated into `"~"(a, ~b)`. It is because `~` is a primitive operator desiged as a sigle character. You still can define the function `"~~" <- function(a,b) {a + b}`, but you can only call it by `"~~"(a,b)` directly for it to work.

On the other hand, you need to be able to specify how a binary operator looks like. Having defined a function `"asdf" <- function(a,b) {a + b}` is not enough and this will **not** work: `a asdf b`

R has something to define binary operators ([R: What are operators like %in% called and how can I learn about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179457/r-what-are-operators-like-in-called-and-how-can-i-learn-about-them)), see large portion of binary operators used like in magrittr's `%>%`  or doParallel's `%dopar%`. Thus it is better to stick to the binary operator *syntax* using `%`, i.e. `<tick>%~~%<tick> <- function(a,b) {a+b}`. Then you can easily access it by using syntactic sugar `a %~~% b`.

Strange stuff, I agree. As for magic tricks: try this at home `"for"(a, 1:10, {print(a)})`. Bonus question: why is `a` visible in the parent frame ?

Comment: Ok, one follow-up. If I do `<tick>%~~%<tick> <- function(e1, e2) paste(e1, e2, sep = "~~")` and supply, say, `x %~~% y` then the R environment is look for objects `x` and `y`. Can I have the input *not* be characters, e.g., `"x" %~~% "y"`?

Comment: `<tick>%~~%<tick> <- function(e1, e2) paste(deparse(substitute(e1)), "~~", deparse(substitute(e2)))` and then: `a %~~% b`

Comment: I assume your solution works as intended? Otherwise I don't get the question.