# How to improve a "seeker" for databases in R? (See code)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, operators

Recently I found the way to create a simple "seeker" for a database using R. 
For example:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- split(mtcars, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$hp))
```

Allow us to find the cars with 8 cylinders and 245 hp and also get the frequencies:

```
mtcars$"8.245"
nrow(mtcars$"8.245")
```

This works only for exact coincidences. For example:

```
>mtcars$"4.100"
NULL
```

So the question is: How this "seeker" may be improved in order to include operators such as >=, <=?

What I mean is, for example, to find all observations with 4 cylinders which have less or equal 100 hp

```
mtcars$"4.<=100" # This code obviously doesn't work it's just for show what I do want to achieve
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you check the `4.100` ie. list element 31, it has 0 rows i.e. the reason you get `NULL`  You may need `mtcars <- split(mtcars, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$hp), drop = TRUE)` to drop all unused cases

Comment: Did you meant `sum(do.call(rbind, mtcars[grep("^4", names(mtcars))])$hp <= 100)`  For this you don't have to split.  It can be directly done on the original dataset i.e. `data(mtcars);sum(mtcars$hp[mtcars$cyl==4] <=100)`

Comment: That's not exactly what I want (my goal is to use the "seeker"), but I assume there's no way to include <= or >= operators in any manner within the code I'm using. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute no idea why you would want to do this, but you can use `eval` and `parse` to create your own function to do that.

```
`%$%` <- function(df, seeker, cols=c("cyl","hp")) {
    strparts <- strsplit(seeker, "\\.")[[1]]
    sk <- ifelse(grepl("^[1-9]", strparts), paste0("==", strparts), strparts)
    s <- paste(paste0("df$", cols, sk), collapse="&")
    ans <- df[eval(parse(text=s)),]
    split(ans, ans[,cols])
}
```

sample usage 1:

```
mtcars %$% "8.245"
# $`8.245`
#        mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
# Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

sample usage 2:

```
mtcars %$% "4.<=100"
# $`4.52`
#              mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Honda Civic 30.4   4 75.7 52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 
# $`4.62`
#            mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.19   20  1  0    4    2
# 
# $`4.65`
#                 mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.9  1  1    4    1
# 
# $`4.66`
#            mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Fiat 128  32.4   4 78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Fiat X1-9 27.3   4 79.0 66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 
# $`4.91`
#               mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Porsche 914-2  26   4 120.3 91 4.43 2.14 16.7  0  1    5    2
# 
# $`4.93`
#             mpg cyl disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710 22.8   4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 
# $`4.95`
#           mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.15 22.9  1  0    4    2
# 
# $`4.97`
#                mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1 97  3.7 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1#
```

Comment: I'm reading Norman Mattlof's "The Art of R Programming" and I'm just trying to go a little further in topics such as lists, classes, etc. Just for research and learning. Thank you for your awesome explanation.

Comment: Your code is quite complex and interesting so I'm reading about all functions involved, but I can't understand how does "seeker" argument is defined if there's no assignation within or outside the function.

Comment: for binary operator, you can use it in between arguments. for e.g `+`(2,3) == 2 + 3 (put backtick around +, i cant get backtick to show in comment here). same here for `%$%`

Comment: So basically, the argument "seeker" pinpoints to the binary operator %$%?

Comment: `%$%` is a function with 2 arguments, you can call it using either `%$%`(df, seekerString) or df `%$%` seekerString

Comment: Now seems pretty clair to me. Could you please suggest me any reference to learn more about binary operators? Thank you again!

Comment: haha good question: maybe start here?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179457/r-what-are-operators-like-in-called-and-how-can-i-learn-about-them

Comment: Thank you again. Norman Matloff's book is quite brief when talking about binary operatoros altough they're very useful to make things by your own. I appreciate your time and patience.