# Can someone explain the definition and use cases of %in% and %% operators in R? I'm having a difficult time understanding them, and their use cases

Tags: r, dplyr, operators

I'm having a difficult time understanding the definition and use cases of `%in%` and `%%` operators. I understand `%in%` as, "find x cases in y". I'm completely lost as to what `%%` means and the use cases behind it. I've looked at the operator cheat sheets provided in R, but am still a bit confused. I'm relatively new to the tidyverse. I appreciate all of your help. Thank you.

I've tried looking at various operator cheat sheets provided by R.

```
nov_dec <- filter(flights, month %in% c(11, 12))
```

and

```
depts <- filter(flights, dep_time %% 2400 <= 600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Operators of the form `%some_text%` are called "binary operators" because they operator on two arguments.  `%%`, the modulo operator, takes the remainder of division of two numbers: `5%%2 = 1`.  `%in%`, the match operator, compares one vector of values to another. You can define your own binary operators by defining functions of two variables as done below:

```
fun1 <- function(x1, x2) { x1 + x2 - 1 }
fun1(2, 3)
# [1] 4

'%fun2' <- function(x1, x2) { x1 + x2 - 1 }
2 %fun2% 3
# [1] 4
```

Note that the quotes around the definition of `%fun2%` are required to escape the special `%` characters.

See this old answer for a more comprehensive overview: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184220/11407644.